# How do I fix my stack overflow error for Sudoku solver c#? Has to do with Recursive function?

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion, stack-overflow, sudoku

I am trying to make a Sudoku solver.
 Whenever I try to run it it gives me a Stack Overflow Error:

> System.StackOverflowException: 'Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown.'

I believe that it probably has to do with the solve function calling on the FindEmpy function too much? 
Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks so much!

```cs
using System;

namespace sudokusolver
{
    class Program
    {
        static public void PrintBoard(int[][] bo)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < bo.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i % 3 == 0 && i != 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("- - - - - - - - - - - - -");
                }
                for (int j = 0; j < bo[0].Length; j++)
                {
                    if (j % 3 == 0 && j != 0)
                    {
                        Console.Write(" | ");
                    }
                    if (j == 8)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(bo[i][j]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write(bo[i][j] + " ");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        static public (int,int) FindEmpty(int[][] bo)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < bo.Length; i++) 
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < bo[0].Length; j++)
                {
                    if (bo[i][j] == 0)
                    { 
                        return (i, j);
                    }
                }
            }
            return (100, 100);
        }

        static public bool Solve(int[][] bo)
        {
            int x;
            int y;
            if (FindEmpty(bo) == (100, 100))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                y = FindEmpty(bo).Item1;
                x = FindEmpty(bo).Item2;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                if (IsValid(bo, i, x, y) == true)
                {
                    bo[y][x] = i;
                    if (Solve(bo) == true)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        bo[y][x] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        static public bool IsValid(int[][] bo, int num, int x, int y)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < bo.Length; i++)
            {
                if (bo[y][i] == num && x != i)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < bo[0].Length; i++)
            {
                if (bo[i][x] == num && y != i)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            int boxx = x / 3;
            int boxy = y / 3;
            for (int i = boxy * 3; i < boxy * 3 + 3; i++)
            {
                for (int j = boxx * 3; j < boxx * 3 + 3; j++)
                {
                    if (bo[i][j] == num && i != y && j != x)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[][] board = {
                new int[] {7,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0},
                new int[] {4,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,3},
                new int[] {0,0,0,2,0,1,0,0,0},
                new int[] {3,0,0,1,8,0,0,9,7},
                new int[] {0,0,9,0,7,0,6,0,0},
                new int[] {6,5,0,0,3,2,0,0,1},
                new int[] {0,0,0,4,0,9,0,0,0},
                new int[] {5,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,6},
                new int[] {0,0,6,0,0,0,0,0,8}
            };

            PrintBoard(board);
            Solve(board);
            PrintBoard(board);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will be honest, I am not exactly sure how your solver works, but I have made a Sudoku solver before. I too had received a stack overflow when the solver was never able to solve the puzzle and thus the program became stuck in an infinite loop.
My guess, is that your solver does not solve the puzzle and gets stuck still trying to no avail.
The only error here is that the solver does not solve all or any puzzles.

Comment: Ah, it's due to `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)`, you're stuck replacing the first "blank" with i == 0 (eg blank).

Comment: you got this error because you create an infinitive loop by calling the `Solve` method in itself. You must change your algorithm for this section.

Comment: Use the debugger: when the StackOverflow occurs look at the callstack which will tell you what your infinite loop is and who caused it. E.g. It will show that your callstack is Method1 M2 M3 M4 M3 M4 M3 M4 and so on, which tells you that M3 or M4 are stuck in an infinite loop probably due to faulty break conditions. Then you can double click on the callstack entries and inspect the methods state and what the values of all variables are.

Answer (score 1):

```cs
        static public bool Solve(int[][] bo)
        {
            int x;
            int y;
            if (FindEmpty(bo) == (100, 100))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                y = FindEmpty(bo).Item1;
                x = FindEmpty(bo).Item2;
            }

-            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
+            for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
            {
                if (IsValid(bo, i, x, y) == true)
                {
                    bo[y][x] = i;
                    if (Solve(bo) == true)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        bo[y][x] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

At some point `IsValid(bo, 0, x, y)` returns true, so you replace the zero with another zero forever.